# How to change item in option menu to have default android icon for profile or settings?

Tags: android

I have just one item in option menu

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

How to change to have default android icon for profile or settings ?
At the moment is just ugly text Settings.

Comment: D you want to show an icon next to your item ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```